# Finding the expected value of Xk

Tags: probability, statistics

Knowing that $ P(X_n = \sqrt{n})=1/2 = P(X_n = -\sqrt{n}) $, How to find the expected value of $X_n$ and the variance of $X_n$ ? I do not understand how to do it at all.

Thank you very much

Comment: Why not just use the definitions?

Comment: I tried this : $ \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} kP(X_n=k)$ and then I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can I do  $ \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} kP(X_n=\sqrt(k)) $ instead ?

Comment: Why are you summing to infinity?  $X_n$ can only take two values (which are not necessarily integers).  And what is $X$?  You did not define that.  Your post refers to $X, X_k$ and $X_n$ and you only defined $X_n$.

Comment: I edited I meant $X_n$ and not X

Answer (score 2):

your random variable can take only 2 values... $\pm\sqrt{n}$ with same probability...the mean is zero....and the variance is exactly the second moment

$$V(X)=n\times 0.5+n\times0.5=n$$

Comment: omg it was so obvious thank you so much. I was dealing with sum to infinity and I completely forgot to check this. Thank you